# Coefficients of Taylor Polynomial

Tags: calculus

Given a function $f(x) \in C^3 $ around $0$ for which $f(x)=ax+bx^2+R_2(x)$ is its Maclaurin sequence. 
Define:

$g(x)= \frac{f(x)}{x} $ when $x\neq 0 $ and $g(0)=1$ .

Given that $a=1$. Is $g'(0)=b$?

I tried substituting the expression into $g$ . Such that, for every $x\neq 0 $ , we have:
$g(x)=1+bx+\frac{R_2(x)}{x} $ .

How can I prove that $b=g'(0)$ ?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$g(x)=1+bx+xe_2(x)\;\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;e_2(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}0\;$$

following [Peano's Remainder + Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) , and so

$$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+bx+xe_2(x)-1}x=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(b+e_2(x)\right)=b$$